# git post-receive hook

Tags: git, git-bash, githooks

Для разделенного деплоя использую хук post-receive:

```
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
branch=echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3
if ["$branch" == "master"]; then
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/frontoffice/prod/html
git checkout -f master
fi
if ["$branch" == "develop"]; then
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/frontoffice/prod/html
git checkout -f develop
fi
done
```

Если запускать вручную, то просто не делает ничего.
Если просто использовать:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/frontoffice/prod/html git checkout -f
```

то всё работает, но необходимо использовать разные директории в зависимости от ветки

Comment: У вас в примере в обоих случаях используется одна и та же директория. Естественно, что checkout будет использовать только ее

Comment: Это опечатка, уже исправлена, тут даже while не срабатывает

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать параметры командной строки(`--work-tree`, `--git-dir`)

```
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    branch=$(echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3)
    git --work-tree=/var/www/frontoffice/prod/html checkout -f $branch
done
```

Comment: Так тоже не сработало, да и деплой будет происходить в одну директорию независимо от ветки :D